# Java finding maximum from array time complexity

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Having an array A of integers with N elements for example {4, 2, 11, -2, 1} i need to find the element with max value from every sub array . Sub arrays are generated this way:

```
for i = 0, leftArray = {4} , rightArry = {2,11,-2,1} 
for i = 1, leftArray = {4,2}, rightArry = {11,-2,1}
for i = 2, leftArray = {4,2,11}, rightArry = {-2, 1}
for i = 3, leftArray = {4,2,11,-2}, rightArry {1}
```

So, i need something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
   //LOGIC HERE
    System.err.println(String.format("Left array max = %s, Right array max = %s",lmax, rmax));
}
```

This would't be a problem if we don't care about time-complexity,
**BUT expected worst-case time complexity is O(N)**

I have not idea how to achive this with O(N) algorithm. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

My current solution:

```
for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        {
            if(i  == A.length - 1)
                break;

            int[] l = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, 0, i + 1);
            int[] r = Arrays.copyOfRange(A, i + 1, A.length);

            Arrays.sort(l);
            Arrays.sort(r);
            System.err.println(l[l.length -1] + " " + r[r.length - 1]);
        }
```

Comment: What is your current solution and what is its complexity?

Comment: you have to generate the subarrays also?

Comment: Do you have to generate them in ascending order only? If not, you could do a loop with ascending `i` to get the max for `leftArray`, then a loop with descending `i` to get the max for `rightArray`.

Comment: @Andy but that wouldn't be O(N) anymore, right?, because you are traversing the array twice

Comment: @AndyTurner That would be O(n) for one split of the array, e.g. for `i = 2`, but if I understand question correctly, you need to provide answer for all `N-1` values of `i`, and that nested loop would be O(n^2).

Comment: @Yassin Hajaj My current solution is to generate the arrays using Arrays.copyFromRange, than sort both arrays asc and get the last element of each. Which isn't O(N) :)

Comment: @Arctigor O(2n) is the same as O(n) ... Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Andreas that's not how I read the question: for `i=0`, we need to find `4` and `11`; for `i=1`, we need to find `4` and `11`; for `i=2`, we need to find `11` and `1` etc. But I may not have got the point :)

Comment: @user3215799 Don't sort. Sorting is O(n*log(n)). Finding max in a loop is O(n). And don't copy. Just iterate part of the array.

Comment: @Arctigor indeed, what YassinHajaj said. A constant multiple of `O(n)` is still `O(n)`.

Comment: you are both right :D

Comment: Why do you need to read sub-arrays? Just iterate the array once, and find the max (which is O(n)).

Comment: I have edited with my current solution

Comment: Why not `for (int i = 0; i < A.length - 1; i++)`?

Comment: @user3215799 Please clarify. Are you asking how to get O(n) for finding the two sub-array max values for a particular value of `i`, or are you asking how to get O(n) listing the two max values for *all* `N-1` values of `i`? I don't think the second is possible.

Comment: @Andreas get O(n) listing the two max values for all N-1 values of i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible in O(n), but I can only think of how to do it in two passes to find the maxes, then another pass to print them:

```
int[] leftMaxes = new int[A.length - 1];
int[] rightMaxes = new int[A.length - 1];

leftMaxes[0] = A[0];
for (int i = 1; i < A.length - 1; ++i) {
  leftMaxes[i] = Math.max(leftMaxes[i-1], A[i]);
}

rightMaxes[A.length - 2] = A[A.length - 1];
for (int i = A.length - 3; i >= 0; --i) {
  rightMaxes[i] = Math.max(rightMaxes[i+1], A[i+1]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < A.length - 1; ++i) {
  System.out.printf("%d: %d %d%n", i, leftMaxes[i], rightMaxes[i]);
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/IPxwUv)

Output:

```
0: 4 11
1: 4 11
2: 11 1
3: 11 1
```

You could combine the `leftMaxes` and printing loops (doing the `rightMaxes` first) to remove one of the passes; but that's not necessary for the required complexity.

And you could combine the `rightMaxes` and `leftMaxes` loops, but I think that would make the code a lot harder to read.

Comment: @Andreas well, ok :) I wasn't counting that one because that's not actually finding the maxes.

Comment: @AndyTurner You new comment at the end of the answer, combining `leftMaxes` and printing would however eliminate the need for the `leftMaxes` array (using running max instead), reducing memory footprint, right?

Comment: @Andreas indeed it would.